# Allow specific user for presence channel

Tags: php, laravel

I made a page(consultation room) where only authorized user can enter. The page is listening to a presence channel. My issue is, do I have to secure the presence channel or is the abort 404 enough ? As of right now, I'm just returning the user data on channel.php.

**Controller**

```
public function consultationRoom(Request $request)
{
    $allowed = Consultation::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('other_users',auth()->user()->id)->first();
    if($allowed){
        return view('pages.consultation');
    }
    abort(404);
}
```

**Consultation.blade.php**

```
<script>
     let channel = Echo.join(`consultation`)
</script>
```

**Channel route**

```
Broadcast::channel('consultation', function ($user) {
    return $user;
});
```

Comment: since the subscribe is done on the JS side, you have to secure the channel to check who can subscribe on the server side. Usually the check is done in the channel route

Comment: A presence channel is a private channel and should have correct authorization. All you need is described in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#authorizing-presence-channels